# Django Random FileField Problem when is deleted

Tags: python, django

I have a project where I upload files with random file name

```
class Exames(models.Model): #models.py
title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
patient = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
exame_pdf = models.FileField(upload_to=RandomFileName('exames'))

def __str__(self):
    return self.title


def filename(self):
    return os.path.basename(self.exame_pdf.name)
```

---

But when I delete a 'Exames' obj I want to the file to be deleted as well so I used this piece of code(It was working before the random file thing)

```
@receiver(models.signals.post_delete, sender=Exames)
def auto_delete_file_on_delete(sender, instance, **kwargs):
"""
Deletes file from filesystem
when corresponding `Exames` object is deleted.
"""
if instance.exame_pdf:
    if os.path.isfile(instance.exame_pdf.path):
        os.remove(instance.exame_pdf.path)

@receiver(models.signals.pre_save, sender=Exames)
def auto_delete_file_on_change(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    """
    Deletes old file from filesystem
    when corresponding `Exames` object is updated
    with new file.
    """
    if not instance.pk:
    return False

try:
    old_file = Exames.objects.get(pk=instance.pk).exame_pdf
except Exames.DoesNotExist:
    return False

new_file = instance.exame_pdf
if not old_file == new_file:
    if os.path.isfile(old_file.path):
        os.remove(old_file.path)
```

> How can I make this work again
>
> The class RandomFileName

```
import os
import uuid
from django.utils.deconstruct import deconstructible
```

@deconstructible
class RandomFileName(object):
    def **init**(self, path):
        self.path = os.path.join(path, "%s%s")

`def __call__(self, _, filename):
    # @note It's up to the validators to check if it's the correct file type in name or if one even exist.
    extension = os.path.splitext(filename)[1]
    return self.path % (uuid.uuid4(), extension)`

Comment: Can you provide us with the code to RandomFileName and provide more information about what exactly isn't working anymore and what is happening? Some good questions to answer when debugging are, what is it doing, what is actually happening, what should be happening.

Comment: Do you get any errors? What does "RandomFileName" do?

Comment: No errors, I've added the randomFileName class